# How can I determine the fundamental period of the signals?

Tags: dsp-core

How can I find the fundamental period of the given signal? Can anyone help me, I am stuck.

1. $x(t) = cos(2πt) + cos(4πt)$
2. $y(t) = cos(2πt) + cos(2t)$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/51918/1629

Comment: Start with the definition.  The fundamental period is the shortest time period for which the signal repeats exactly.  Mathematically this is expressed as x(t) = x(t+T).  Obviously, once you find T, then 2T, 3T, 4T and any integer multiple of T is also a period (a repeat section of the signal).  With that in mind, and if it isn't adequate, follow Gilles' link.